# Painting complete view in grayscale

Tags: android

In the app I am working on we want to show that user that some items are disabled. The way we want to visuals that is by drawing the views in grayscale. These views can contain images, text, buttons etc, pretty much anything.

So, is there a way to make a whole view draw itself in grayscale?

This is the current solution, which is too slow to use for listview items:

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    final Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
    final Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);
    ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
    colorMatrix.setSaturation(0);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix));
    super.dispatchDraw(tempCanvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(tempBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
}
```

Comment: @Funkystein that would not draw the views in grayscale? The images the app gets will still be in color. Its only some of the view of a whole layout that should be in this state.

Comment: I have updated my question with what I have right now, and the problems with it.

Comment: @Funkystein you are not helping. Please read the question again.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489573/disabling-and-changing-style-of-individual-listview-items-with-custom-adapter-in